# Retrofit Post on Android kotlin not working but working on postman

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to Hit the API using the Retrofit Post method to put the form data but the problem is that the API returns null all the time even if I try to pass the params. I tested the API by running it in Postman it works fine and I also added internet permission and set usesCleartextTraffic to true under manifest.xml, so it would be really helpful if anyone guides me to rectify this issue.

**Output When I tried to debugg**

```
call = Unresolved reference: call
response = Unresolved reference: response
this = {MainActivity@9661} 
params = {HashMap@10022}  size = 5
 "password" -> "Ram@123"
 "countryCode" -> {Integer@10042} 91
 "name" -> "Ranjith"
 "mobile" -> {Long@10046} 99********
 "emailID" -> "var***@gmail.com"
```

**Response back from the API with body null all the time**

```
response = {Response@10220} "Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=http://*.***.***.***:***0/api/v1/****/auth/register}"
 body = null
 errorBody = {ResponseBody$1@10224} 
  content = {Buffer@10228} "[text={"code":400,"error":true,"msg":"Enter a valid name"}]"
  contentLength = 52
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        uploadBt.setOnClickListener {
            callApi()
        }

    }

    private fun callApi() {

        val params = HashMap<String?, Any?>()
        params["name"] = "Ranjith"
        params["mobile"] = 99*******
        params["emailID"] = "var***@gmail.com"
        params["password"] = "Ram@123"
        params["countryCode"] = 91

            RetrofitClient.instance.registerUser(params)
                      .enqueue(object : Callback<DefaultResponse>{
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<DefaultResponse>, response: Response<DefaultResponse>) {
                    print(response)
                    if(response.isSuccessful)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, response.body()?.msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }else
                    {
                        var jsonObject: JSONObject? = null
                        try {
                            jsonObject = JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())

                            val code = jsonObject.getString("code")
                            val error = jsonObject.getString("error")
                            val message = jsonObject.getString("msg")

                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, message+"\n"+code+"\n"+error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        } catch (e: JSONException) {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            e.printStackTrace()

                        }
                    }

                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<DefaultResponse>, t: Throwable) {

                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }

            })
    }

}
```

**Interface Api**

```
interface Api {

    @FormUrlEncoded

    @POST("/api/v1/******/****/register")

    fun registerUser(

        @FieldMap params: HashMap<String?, Any?>

        
    ): Call<DefaultResponse>
}
```

**RetrofitClient.kt object class**

```
object RetrofitClient {
  
    private const val BASE_URL = "http://3.1**.**5.1*1:****"

    private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor { chain ->
            val original = chain.request()

            val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .method(original.method(), original.body())

            val request = requestBuilder.build()
            chain.proceed(request)
        }.build()

    val instance: Api by lazy{
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
        retrofit.create(Api::class.java)
    }
}
```

**DefaultResponse.kt  model data class**

```
data class DefaultResponse(
    @SerializedName("code")
    val code: Int,
    @SerializedName("err")
    val error: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("msg")
    val msg: String
    )
```

[Through Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWD21.jpg)

Comment: is the backend dealing with cookies?

Comment: I am dealing with the front end part but when I asked this to the backend team, they said no.

Comment: Being null will point to a deserialisation problem. Taking the JSON response and applying it to the `Response<DefaultResponse>` Which you are then trying to convert to `JSONObject` Try changing the API return type to `Call<JSONObject>`

Comment: can you elaborate a bit on how to do that?

Comment: based on your postman screenshot, the request body is raw text/json, not FormUrlEncoded. please make you sure the server also support POST request with form-urlencoded parameter. otherwise you should modify your request to not encoded

Comment: please also redact your credential (email, phone number also password etc) when posting in public website

Comment: @hakim Indeed the server supports POST request with form-urlencoded parameters.

Comment: @Ranjith make sure to test it first on Postman. just to make sure it is works

Comment: @hakim yeah it works, Check out the screenshot I added with the question.

Comment: in the screenshot the payload data is not form-urlencoded format

Comment: you are welcome 